# Add to rows instead of column in Parents-Childs relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is bill of material structure data for a Supplement.
There is Parent (ParentPart) and then the component and each component also may used other component.

Now with LEFT JOIN I was able to add the columns but I wonder how I can have this as only 2 columns and have ParentPart and then the all the components.

So it will look like:

| ParentPart | Component |
| --- | --- |
| WN3403 | NF0533K |
| WN3403 | 571012 |
| ... | ... |

Thank you

[image: Picture added]

Comment: Please don't post massive images like that for data / code which you can barely read. Instead post as formatted text which is much easier to read and copy+paste.

Comment: [Do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the 6 numbers and conditional column creation as follows:

```
with cte (num) as
(select 1 union all
select num+1 from cte where num <= 6),
your_query as (<put_your_query_here>)
select t.parent_part,
       case when c.num = 1 then level_1_component,
            when c.num = 2 then level_2_component,
            when c.num = 3 then level_3_component,
            when c.num = 4 then level_4_component,
            when c.num = 5 then level_5_component,
            when c.num = 6 then level_6_component
        end as component
   from cte c cross join your_query t
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to unpivot the data.

Use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (parent_part, level_1_component),
             (parent_part, level_2_component),
             (parent_part, level_3_component),
             (parent_part, level_4_component),
             (parent_part, level_5_component),
             (parent_part, level_6_component)
     ) v(parent_part, component)
where component is not null;
```

I would recommend adding additional columns, such as the level and the immediate parent:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (parent_part, level_1_component, NULL, 1),
             (parent_part, level_2_component, level_1_component, 2),
             (parent_part, level_3_component, level_2_component, 3),
             (parent_part, level_4_component, level_3_component, 4),
             (parent_part, level_5_component, level_4_component, 5),
             (parent_part, level_6_component, level_5_component, 6)
     ) v(parent_part, component, parent_component, lev)
where component is not null;
```